# Jquery data table filter/search icon image in the table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, datatable, icons

I have a Jquery data table column with icon image in each cell:

```
<tr><td><i class="icon-glass"></i></td></tr>
<tr><td><i class="icon-music"></i></td></tr>
<tr><td><i class="icon-glass"></i></td></tr>
<tr><td><i class="icon-music"></i></td></tr>
```

I would like to filter for only `class="icon_name1"` and display on the data table. Currently with normal data table initialization, it will not display any data from that column. Is there any customization that needed to filter this kind of data? Thanks for comments.

Edited:

For example, `class="icon-glass"` will display icon from one of these: http://andymatthews.net/code/jquery-mobile-icon-pack/font-awesome/faicons.png in my data table column. Can I only filter only `icon-glass` in data table when it is not a word? I would only like to show the following in my table:

```
<tr><td><i class="icon-glass"></i></td></tr>
<tr><td><i class="icon-glass"></i></td></tr>
```

Is that possible?

Comment: Also, you shouldn't have 2 ids with the same value, instead use classes.

Comment: @YosepKim kindly check the revised version of my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for those who are confused and mark down this post, thanks for reading out there, I have solved my own issue by setting another column with a flag that is not visible by browser but is searchable:

```
<tr><td><i class="icon-glass"></i></td><td>glass</td></tr>
<tr><td><i class="icon-music"></i></td><td>music</td></tr>
<tr><td><i class="icon-glass"></i></td><td>glass</td></tr>
<tr><td><i class="icon-music"></i></td><td>music</td></tr>
```

Setting the second column to as such:

```
{ "bVisible": false }
```

Then when search 'glass' in the search, it will do the filter and show the glass icon row. Happy coding!